# Google Contact API v3 - Can't create name/title when creating contacts

Tags: google-api, google-shared-contacts

I'm using Google Contacts API v3 docs, OAuth Playground 2.0.

I'm able to pull all contacts via a get request. I can use POST to create a new contact but can't seem to populate the name fields, among others. The email and phone number populate fine.

I've been using atom/xml in the request body verbatim from the Contacts API v3 doc as below.

```
    <atom:entry xmlns:atom='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom'
    xmlns:gd='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005'>
  <atom:category scheme='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind'
    term='http://schemas.google.com/contact/2008#contact'/>
  <gd:name>
     <gd:givenName>Elizabeth</gd:givenName>
     <gd:familyName>Bennet</gd:familyName>
     <gd:fullName>Elizabeth Bennet</gd:fullName>
  </gd:name>
  <atom:content type='text'>Notes</atom:content>
  <gd:email rel='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#work'
    primary='true'
    address='liz@gmail.com' displayName='E. Bennet'/>
  <gd:email rel='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#home'
    address='liz@example.org'/>
  <gd:phoneNumber rel='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#work'
    primary='true'>
    (206)555-1212
  </gd:phoneNumber>
  <gd:phoneNumber rel='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#home'>
    (206)555-1213
  </gd:phoneNumber>
  <gd:im address='liz@gmail.com'
    protocol='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#GOOGLE_TALK'
    primary='true'
    rel='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#home'/>
  <gd:structuredPostalAddress
      rel='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#work'
      primary='true'>
    <gd:city>Mountain View</gd:city>
    <gd:street>1600 Amphitheatre Pkwy</gd:street>
    <gd:region>CA</gd:region>
    <gd:postcode>94043</gd:postcode>
    <gd:country>United States</gd:country>
    <gd:formattedAddress>
      1600 Amphitheatre Pkwy Mountain View
    </gd:formattedAddress>
  </gd:structuredPostalAddress>
</atom:entry>
```

Any help is much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I got stung by this, too. I was neglecting to add this HTTP Header to the request:

```
GData-Version: 3.0
```

Before v3, the way to indicate the name was `<atom:title>Full Name</atom:title>` instead of `<gd:name>...</gd:name>`. But I guess it's better to just add the header.

Comment: Tried it. But still the title field is empty for `some` contacts.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you must need to add GData-Version to your HTTP request Header:

```
[request setValue:@"3.0" forHTTPHeaderField:@"GData-Version"];
```